# How to send the data captured in android app to an email address?

Tags: android

I' m new to Android app development. I am trying to create a mobile application that has three entry fields. i.e: 
1. Name 
2. Contact Number 
3. Email Address( Receiver's).

I want to email the first and second entry of the input data captured to the email address (the third entry ) on click of Send button.

Comment: check how you can send email with attachment in google

Comment: Check this out - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 1):

First get your name, contact number and email address from the textbox after user enter it... like this..

```
String name= textbox1.gettext.toString().trim();
String Cnum= textbox2.gettext.toString().trim();
String email= textbox3.gettext.toString().trim();



Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{email});   // email is value from user
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please type following codes on button click.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```